# How to directly make use of JAR file from main resources folder Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This might be a slightly unusual question but I have a unique situation where something like this is a good solution for me.

I have a jar file (called engine.jar) within my src/main/resources. How can I directly make use of this jar from my main JAVA class? (add this in the build path?) but....

I have another JAR file (of the exact same name i.e. engine.jar) within my Maven Dependencies library which has slightly different code. I want to make use of this jar later on in my main class.

How can I accomplish this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the jar should not matter by itself. Have you tried renaming 'engine.jar' so there is no conflict and then adding it to the build path?